# onsenui and jaydata doesn't coexist

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui, jaydata

when using this order :

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/datajs-1.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydatamodules/angular.js"></script>
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: Class.extend is not a function  
    at Object.<anonymous> (onsenui.js:13049)  
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4535)  
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4387)  
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4535)  
    at angular.js:4352  
    at getService (angular.js:4494)  
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4526)  
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4387)  
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4535)  
    at angular.js:4352
```

And when using this order:

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/datajs-1.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydatamodules/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
```

note: edited to correct the order

```
jaydata.js:3342 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution based on [Ilia Yatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5803286/ilia-yatchev) answer so thanks to him.

first I used the downloaded jaydata files instead of the online files since it contains the code change that [Ilia Yatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5803286/ilia-yatchev) mentionned on his answer

```
var Class;
$data.Class = Class = new ClassEngineBase();
```

note : the order isn't a problem now

```
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<script src="lib/datajs-1.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jaydata.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jaydatamodules/angular.js"></script>
```

then in the code we save a reference of the created entity:

```
var Todo = $data.Entity.extend("Todo", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Task: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 200 },
    DueDate: { type: Date },
    Completed: { type: Boolean }
});
```

and we save a reference of the created context:

```
var TodoDatabase = $data.EntityContext.extend("TodoDatabase", {
    Todos: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Todo }
});
```

then we can safely work these references:

```
var todoDB = new TodoDatabase("MyTodoDatase");
todoDB.onReady(function() {
    var tasks = todoDB.Todos.addMany([
        { Task: 'Step0: Get this this list', Completed: true },
        { Task: 'Step1: Define your data model'},
        { Task: 'Step2: Initialize data storage'}
    ]);
    todoDB.saveChanges(function() {
        tasks.forEach( function(todo) { alert(todo.Id) });
    });
});
```

if I don't save reference to the entity and the context I get this error

```
angular.js:12722 ReferenceError: Contact is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:343)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4535)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4387)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4535)
    at angular.js:4352
    at getService (angular.js:4494)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4526)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9380)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8497)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7929)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like both jaydata and onsenui are using `window.Class`, however their implementations differ significantly. Onsen uses John Resig's implementation while in jaydata's version `Class` is actually an instance of their `ClassEngineBase`. The problem of making these two implementations work together at least from my point of view is that in jaydata's version `Class` is actually an instance rather than a function. If it was a function it would've been easy to merge the two implementations by just adding the extend method to jaydata's implementation.

You could still try to do that, but it's not going to be as easy and some new bugs may occur if not done properly.

So your options are:

1. Still try to merge the implementations
2. Modify Onsen UI
3. Modify Jaydata
4. Wait for one of the two libs to fix the issue

1.
Sequence: [`jaydata`, `onsenui`, `patch`], where patch is a modified version of the onsenui version.

```
(function(){
  var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
  this.Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super = this.prototype || {};
    initializing = true;
    var constructor = typeof this === 'function' ? this : function(){};
    var prototype = new constructor();
    initializing = false;

    for (var name in prop) {
      prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" &&
        typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ?
        (function(name, fn){
          return function() {
            var tmp = this._super;
            this._super = _super[name];
            var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
            this._super = tmp;
            return ret;
          };
        })(name, prop[name]) :
        prop[name];
    }

    function Class() {
      if (!initializing && this.init)
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    Class.prototype = prototype;
    Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;
    return Class;
  };
})();
```

However I haven't really tested it if it works, and there may be some issues.

2. You aren't including `angular-onsenui.js`, so I guess you're using onsen 1, not onsen 2. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8riu7jspaz7e9p/onsenui_1.3.15_modified.js?dl=1)'s a slightly modified version of `1.3.15` which should not have collisions (not tested, sorry).
3. In JayData they're storing the class in `$data.Class` so it turns out that there are only 2 places where the global one is used in `http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js`

   ```
   2874: $data.Class = Class = new ClassEngineBase();
   3342: global["$C"] = function () { Class.define.apply(Class, arguments); };
   ```

You could either remove the `= Class` from the first line and change both cases of the second line from `Class` to `$data.Class`, or just write `var Class;` on line 2873. - Actually it seems they already have [implemented this change](https://github.com/jaystack/jaydata/blob/7f0632b2e6d70ea9cf3f0634957e82a3125f22e4/src/TypeSystem/TypeSystem.js#L859) but it seems like it's not in the online version yet.

4. So if you don't want to change the files I guess maybe JayData could have the updated version somewhere. For Onsen - the developement of Onsen 1 is already finished and we are working only on Onsen 2. The same bug will probably persist with the current beta, but it probably won't be too long before we fix it.

Comment: I verified jaydata.js file and I found that var Class; already exist
here is the code I found
var Class;
$data.Class = Class = new ClassEngineBase();
but based on this suggestion I found a solution to the problem :
by adding reference to each object I extends I'll post an answer for more details
Thank You!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. We will probably fix this in Onsen so that it doesn't cause issues, but that will be in Onsen 2. When we fix it maybe you could be interested in using the newer verion :)

Comment: yep I'll wait for it, Thank You